# Using str_replace to replace HTML comments with PHP tags

Tags: php

Using PHP, I'm trying to create a function that will replace specific opening and closing HTML comment with opening and closing PHP tags.
What's happening is when I enter the commented HTML to be the subject string, it is being embedded into the HTML document rather then being replaced with PHP tags. However, when I enter something other than HTML comments it's fine - as you'd expect.
var_dump() returns string(32) "" and NULL for $foo and $bar respectively.
For example,the function below is intended to replace:

```
    <!--CODE echo"hello world"; CODE--!>
```

With:

```
    <?php echo"hello world"; ?>
```

The code:

```
    <?php
    function code($subject){
        $php=array("<?php","?>"); //the replace string array
        $html=array("<!--CODE","CODE--!>"); //the search string array
        $subject=str_replace($html,$php,$subject); //search the subject and replace strings
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $foo=$_POST['foo'];
        $bar=code($foo);
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    var_dump($foo);
    var_dump($bar);
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas? Would appreciate your input.

Comment: Just a little note. The closing comment symbol for HTML comments is not `--!>`, but just `-->`. Example: `<!-- this is a comment -->`.

Comment: @Overflowh Closing HTML comments noted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you tried to accomplish.

```
<?php
    function code($subject) {
        $php = array("<?php", "?>"); //the replace string array
        $html = array("<!--CODE", "CODE-->"); //the search string array
        return str_replace($html, $php, $subject); //search the subject and replace strings
    }

    if(isset($_POST['foo'])) {
        $foo = $_POST['foo'];
        $bar = code($foo);
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($foo)) {
    echo 'foo = ';
    var_dump($foo);
}

if (isset($bar)) {
    echo 'bar = ';
    var_dump($bar);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="foo" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I edited the comment closing tag in you `$html` array with the HTML standard comment closing tag and edited the third row of your `code()` function. Now the values is not assigned back to `$subject` but is retured (`return str_replace($html, $php, $subject)`).

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, what happens now is the function will only replace `<!--CODE` and `CODE-->` with `<!--?php` and `?-->` respectively. Also viewing the source of the document once the form has been submitted, the quotes are escaped i.e. `echo\"hello world\";`. Perhaps htmlentities() could be of use here?

Comment: If I use htmlentities() to encode str_replace() i.e. `return htmlentities(str_replace($html,$php,$subject));`, the HTML comment tags will convert to PHP tags but they are displayed in the browser and will have the quotes escaped.